# .net core mac os. Can't find "System.Buffer"

Tags: .net, .net-core

After publish test application, I try run my app

**bash-3.2$ dotnet bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/publish/testapp.dll**

and get next error:

> Error: assembly specified in the dependencies manifest was not found
>   -- package: 'System.Buffers', version: '4.0.0-rc2-24027', path:  'lib/netstandard1.1/System.Buffers.dll'

Environment: .net core rc2

project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any errors or warnings from `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build` or `dotnet publish`? Did you do anything special, or is this just a Hello World ASP.NET application?

Comment: I didn't get any errors from `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish`